# Is "mandatoriness" a commonly used word?

Tags: phrases

Is "mandatoriness" a commonly used word? I am intending to use it in a technical paper.

Comment: To answer your question, No.  Now for a question of my own - could you please provide the context?  I would imagine there is a better way of saying what you are trying to say.

Comment: Are you trying to describe the state of being mandatory such as whether or not something is mandatory?  Context will help, as will your own research for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not. Mandatory is common. *Mandatory requirements, information, format* etc., yes.

*Mandatoriness*, no.

A search of COPA, academic, turned up no results.